# Horizontal scroll bar on container with fixed header issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

A bit of a tricky one! I guess, its easy by setting the height of the container, but it breaks the sticky header in fixed position.

I want to be able to see the scrollbar in both directions X and Y on `.scrollable-content`

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hqb4u0ps/)

Answer (score -1):

Remove `overflow-x: scroll;` `css` on `.container-compare`

Comment: is not that simple, if you look at the header, without the overflow-x it won't move!

Comment: also give `display: inline-block` to `wrapper-compare`. Now header also can be scrollable

Comment: did you notice I have a sticky navigation? thats why I'm asking for help.